# Explain Pass-by-Result and Pass-by-Value-Result in very simple terms

Tags: parameters

I do not understand how this works, can someone please explain it? I provided some code along the simplicity I am looking for. Please help.

```
void function(int a, int b)
{
   int temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}

int main()
{
   int a = 2;
   int b = 3;

   function(a, b);
   return 0;
};
```

Edit: I think they are similar so I edited the title to reflect the desire for both descriptions.